# nuget references appear missing after restore but aren't

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

After I restore nugget packages my solution builds but intellisense says the references don't exist and I get what looks like errors but are false positive. This only seems to happen in my test projects. The only way I have found to fix it is to go into the references for each project that reports errors and view the properties. Once I open one the broken reference in the properties window all of the broken references for that project magically get fixed.

Just to be clear - the restore is working - its just VS doesn't think so; it puts the missing reference icon on the reference and intellisense reports errors on any code that uses the reference. It all builds and runs fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nuget references appear missing after restore but aren't

You need use the NuGet command line in the Package Manager Console:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

to force reinstall the package references into project after restore nuget package.

NuGet Restore **only restores files in the packages directory** (\packages folder ), but does not restore files inside your project or otherwise modify your project, in other words, **NuGet will not reinstall the package references in the project**. After you restore the packages, the packages are re-download to the packages directory, so the package references are broken temporary, then the intellisense reports missing reference errors on any code that uses the references.

To resolve this question, you can use the "`Update-Package -reinstall`" command to force reinstall the package references, after that, all references are reinstalled, this weird behavior will disappear.

Hope this can help you.